# How to get elements in Jagged array in C# (UNITY 3d)

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I created a 3d int array

```
public int[,,]  npcState =  new int[,,] {
    {
        {0,0}
    },{
        {1,9,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {1,1,1},{10,10}
    },{
        {8,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}
    },{
        {10,7},{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2}
    },{
        {1,1,1} ,{1,1,1}
    },{
        {8,11},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}
    },{
        {0,1,1},{1,1,1}
    }
};
```

My questions are

**1.) How to assign value at run time**

**2.)How to check array each rows and column using loop like**

```
for(int i =0 ; i < firstDimensionalLength ; i ++){
  for(int j =0 ; j < secondDimensionalLength; j ++){
     for(int k =0 ; k < thirdDimensionalLength; k ++){
// print (npcState[i,j,k]); 
   }
  }
}
```

If it constant length for all dimensional , it is easy to find elements . But if it dynamic how to find each elements in  particular positions

Comment: You can't define a 3D array like that. All inner arrays have to be the same length. You can only do that with jagged arrays.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Work on that first.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as per commenter's suggestion I am adding a compiling version of the multi-dimensional array declaration:

```
public int[,,] npcState =  new int[,,] {
    {
       {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {1,9,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
       {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    },{
        {2,2,2},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
    }
};
```

If you really want to use `for` loop, then you can access the length of the dimensions by using `GetLength()` method:

```
var firstDimensionalLength = npcState.GetLength(0);
var secondDimensionalLength = npcState.GetLength(1);
var thirdDimensionalLength = npcState.GetLength(2);
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx)

Comment: I would recommend to also add a compiling version of the initializing of such an array because the one in his question isn't valid

Answer (score 1):

In case you want just to scan the entire array, try using `foreach`:

```
foreach (int item in npcState) {
  // print (item); 

  if (SomeCondition(item)) {
    ...
  }  
}
```

please notice, that the loop *doesn't depend* on array's dimensions (it will be the same for 1d, 2d, 3d etc. arrays)

**Edit:** if you want item's *location* (i.e. `i, j, k` indexes) you have to put

```
// In many cases you can put 0 instead of `npcState.GetLowerBound()` since 
// arrays are zero based by default
for (int i = npcState.GetLowerBound(0); i <= npcState.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
  for (int j = npcState.GetLowerBound(1); j <= npcState.GetUpperBound(1); ++j)
    for (int k = npcState.GetLowerBound(2); k <= npcState.GetUpperBound(2); ++k) {
      int item = npcState[i, j, k];
      ...
    }
```

**Edit 2**: Since the question has been edited and *N-D* array has been turned into *jagged* one the solution should have been changed as well:

```
  int[][][] npcState = new int[][][] {
    new int[][] {
      new int[] { 0, 0 } },
    new int[][] {
      new int[] { 1, 9, 1},
      new int[] { 1, 0, 1},
      new int[] { 1, 1, 1}, },
    new int[][] {
      new int[] { 2, 2, 2},
      new int[] { 1, 1, 1},
      new int[] { 1, 1, 1}, }, 
    // ...
  };

 // Array of array of array can be just flatten twice
 foreach (var item in npcState.SelectMany(line => line.SelectMany(row => row))) {
   ...
 }
```

Location preserved loop will be

```
 for (int i = 0; i < npcState.Length; ++i) 
   for (int j = 0; j < npcState[i].Length; ++j) 
     for (int k = 0; k < npcState[i][j].Length; ++k) {
       int item = npcState[i][j][k];
       ...   
     }
```

Comment: This code will give every elements ,  I need each elements in particular position

Comment: how to find particular element in particular position in array .

Comment: @Liju Thomas: in case you want not just `item` itself, but its *location* (i.e. `i`, `j`, `k` indexes) as well you have to scan dimensions: e.g. `for (int i = npcState.GetLowerBound(0); i <= npcState.GetUpperBound(0); i++)` for the 1st one (see my edit)

Comment: @Liju Thomas: What doesn't work, please? Do you have an exception? The code doesn't compile; the outcome doesn't match the expected one?

Comment: Result is  (0,0,0) = 0   (0,0,1) = 0  (1,0,0) = 1 (1,0,1) = 9 . not getting third (1,0,2)  . only getting two elements per each row

Comment: @Liju Thomas: in case you want *jagged* array `int[][][]` (array of array of array) you should loop on each *array*, not on each *dimension* (as in 3d array - `int[,,]`)

Comment: int xxx [][][] = new int [10][][];  how to add elements in this array and how to get each elements

Comment: @Liju Thomas: `int xxx [][][] = new int [10][][];` - an array of `10` (the 1st index) of arrays of array. Or jagged array of jagged array; `xxx[1][2][3]` - to get an item; `xxx.Length` - number of items in the outer array, `xxx[n1].Length` - to get number of items in the *middle* array, `xxx[n1][n2].Length` to get number of items in the inner array

Comment: int xxx [][][] = new int [10][][]; how to put elements in middle array and inner array

Comment: @Liju Thomas: if you want just to *put* an item: `x[3] = new int[][] {new int[] {4, 5, 6}, new int [] {7, 8}}`;  `x[3][0] = new int[] {10, 20, 30};`; finally `x[3][0][1] = 123;`. In case you want to *insert* an item, *add up* an item (i.e. *resize* the array) you've chosen the wrong collection kind; it should have been `List<List<List<int>>>`

Comment: @Liju Thomas: a possibile cause of the *Invalid rank specifier error* is that you've declared, say `10` items: `int xxx [][][] = new int [10][][] {...}`  but initialized just `1` or `9` or `11`...

Comment: how to initialise properly

Comment: @Liju Thomas: in my answer I've started `npcState` initialization `int[][][] npcState = ...`; can you, please, have a llok at the pattern and complete it?

Comment: How to put elements like x[3] = new int[][] {new int[] {4, 5, 6} ; this is not working

Comment: @Liju Thomas: haven't you missed `}`? `x[3] = new int[][] {new int[] {4, 5, 6}} ;` (notice two `}}`)

Comment: x[3] = new int[][] {new int[] {4, 5, 6}} ; is not working

Comment: `int [][][] x = new int[10][][]; x[3] = new int[][] { new int[] { 4, 5, 6 } };` does work, test: `Console.Write(string.Join(", ", x[3][0]));`

Comment: Its not working in Unity3d . Showing following errors  1) error CS0178: Invalid rank specifier: expected `,' or `]'  error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration